# stripping out characters in ansible

Tags: ansible

We currently have this naming convention in our environment

```
abc.dev.example.com ## dev servers
abc.staging.example.com ## staging servers
abc.example.com ### prod servers
```

As part of my playbook, I have the following which pretty much prints `abc.dev.example.com`

```
   vars:
    env: dev
   tasks:
   - name: show vars
     debug: msg=abc.{{env | default([])}}.example.com
```

However when i leave the env variables blank, i get the following `abc..example.com`. I need it to be `abc.example.com`.

Any idea how to scrip out the extra `.` character in ansible?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like that:

```
- debug:
    msg: "abc.{{ env + '.' if env|default() else '' }}example.com"
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can make your conditional explicit instead of relying on default()

```
 debug: msg=abc.{% if thing is defined %}{{ thing }}.{% else %}{% endif %}example.com
```